# Two Dimensional number density distribution Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability

I don't know how to plot two dimensional number density distribution.

```
P(R,Pm) = N* x exp^(-r+Pm)


N* = 22,200
R = 0,1,2...,10
Pm = 0,1,2...,10
```

Can any one suggest me How to plot this in Matlab? I don't have any idea for 2-dimensional probability distribution.

Comment: This is not Matlab code ... please start by learning the basic syntax in the documentation.

Comment: Check `ndgrid` Matlab function

Comment: yes, Its not a matlab code but we can plot this in matlab since we have two variables? as a two dimensional distribution function?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate a 2D grid of spatial points, then use these as input into `P` and plot your data.  A [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) or [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) plot should suffice.  As such, assuming `R` is on the `x` axis and `Pm` is on the `y` axis:

```
[R,Pm] = ndgrid(0:10,0:10);
N = 22200;
P = N*exp(-R+Pm);
surf(R,Pm,P);
```

We get the following.  Make sure you click on the picture below to experience the reaction I had when I produced this plot:

[image]